# "enableKafka" property is ignored in Azure RM template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventhub

I have a ARM template for EventHub and i set "kafkaEnabled" property to false, bo Kaffka is always turned on. Why is that?

```json
"resources": [
...
 "properties": {
"kafkaEnabled": false
}
]
```

Complete template available [here](https://github.com/krolikowski80/Szkola_Chmury/blob/master/Azure/az304/13_02/lab/Lab.3_Building_Enterprise/EventHUB/azuredeploy.json)

[image]

Comment: @JimXu thak you, but I'll rather wait for a more certain answer, not assumptions.

Comment: I have contacted Microsoft support engineer. He tells me that it is by design. We cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, your template has no problem. It seems that Azure backend server forces this function to be enabled and we cannot disable it. For more details, please refer to the request I catch when I deploy the template.

[image]